# when Linux standard account daemon is /sbin/nologin, is there any way to change a file owned by it?

Tags: linux, security

I'm doing the threat hunting. I found one file, it's username is daemon, groupname is root. the file permission is set in SGID (when any user run it, it would run as root).
In my user setting, daemon, a standard linux user, is set to /usr/sbin/nologin. I know I cannot use any bash for this account.
My question would be: is there any way to change the file owned by daemon in this setting. From security perspective, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: The question doesn't really have an answer unless you provide specifics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"is there any way to change the file owned by daemon" - yes.  If running as `root` you can use `chown(1)`.  If you can, use `sudo`.

"From security perspective, do you have any suggestion?" - without a lot more information, no.  If the file has been set up like this, there is probably a good reason.  Changing it may open security vulnerabilities, or may close off capabilities.

Comment: the file is a /usr/sbin/xxxx file. It's a common command we use in daily operation. by my understanding, daemon is able to edit the file with any content he want, the obstacle here is how to edit the file without shell

Comment: This is probably a legacy application.  "xxxx" isn't very informative!  The daemon user and daemon group are unprivileged and were historically used to allow daemons to run without privilege.  Modern systems are more likely to create a specific user for the daemon, for instance gdm runs as user gdm in group gdm or apache runs as apache:apache.

Comment: @Martin: But that is distribution specific, on Debian and Ubuntu (and other derivatives?) Apache typically runs as www-data.

Comment: Very true, but the principle remains valid.  I just used a couple of examples out of many.  The point though is that Apache runs on your distro as www-data, and not daemon as it might have done years back.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said which file it is so it's hard to say anything from a security perspective.

But permissions aren't checked when your (effective) uid is 0, i.e. when you're root.

You can also start bash (or any other command) as "daemon" with `sudo -u daemon /bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. it's a /usr/bin/xxxxx file. generally, it should be owned by root:root, but now, it's daemon:root, 2755. I don't understand why file matters. Basically, if daemon was able to edit the file, it can do anything as root.
I'm thinking from the hacking aspect, how can I do the permission escalating  in this situation without root permission.

Comment: The *exact* file matters, as that would allow us to judge whether there is a reason why that file is owned by daemon. And as it's basically impossible to login as daemon, while this does provide a way to elevate permissions from daemon to root, this is probably not a security risk worth considering, there's plenty of other things to do.